# R compare current row entry to the next row entry (on same column)

Tags: r

I have something like the following, as a dataframe

```
ID      Date       Bug
3452   02/01/2004  A
3452   02/01/2004  B
6532   06/01/2004  D
8732   09/01/2004  C
3466   20/01/2004  A
```

I wish to loop through the whole thing, and go through each entry in the ID column first, if two ID's are the same subsequently, then I wish to move to the Date column, and compare it to the following row's Date. I want to check if both dates lie within a 14 day window. If so, they need to be marked as one entity.

Comment: Can you show expected output for the data shared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert the 'Date' column to `Date` class, grouped by 'ID', create the 'flag' column by taking the `diff`erence between adjacent 'Date' and check if it is less than 14

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
   mutate(Date = dmy(Date)) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(flag = c("No", "Yes")[1 + c(FALSE, diff(Date) < 14)]) %>%
   ungroup
```

or get the difference between the current date and the `lag` of that date

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(Date = dmy(Date)) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(flag =  replace_na(as.integer(difftime(Date, lag(Date), units = 'day')) < 14, FALSE)) %>%
   ungroup
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(3452L, 3452L, 6532L, 8732L, 3466L),
Date = c("02/01/2004", 
"02/01/2004", "06/01/2004", "09/01/2004", "20/01/2004"), Bug = c("A", 
"B", "D", "C", "A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. So I tested this and it's working, Is it possible to have the Flag column to display a custom label instead of true or false? For example, if True, say 'Yes'. If false, say 'No'.

Comment: @Isa Updated the post.  When you add 1 to the logical vector, TRUE becomes 2 and FALSE 1 (as by default it is 1 0) and use this index to replace values by passing a vector (c("No", "Yes")) i.e. wherever there is 2 it is "Yes" and 1 replaced with "No" as the position of "No" in the passing vector is 1.  BTW, we add 1 as the indexing starts from 1 in `R`